# Not getting the actual image stored path from response params in ruby on rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, titanium-mobile, image-uploading

I am using image capture using titanium and then upload using ruby on rails.
In titanium after capturing the image, I am simply hitting the `/img_uploaders/upload` URL of rails to call.
As a result the post request to the `upload` method is sent.

This is what I am getting in a console:-

```
Started POST "/img_uploaders/upload" for 192.168.0.180 at 2012-12-19 20:40:31 +0
530
Processing by ImgUploadersController#upload as MULTIPART_FORM
  Parameters: {"media"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x569e308 @original
_filename="tixhr1442726854.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-
Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\"tixhr1442726854.jpeg\"\r\nCon
tent-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n", @tempfile=#<Fil
e:C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20121219-3924-is4hsq>>}
  ←[1m←[35m (49.0ms)←[0m  BEGIN
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (82.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mINSERT INTO `img_uploaders` (`avatar_content_ty
pe`, `avatar_file_name`, `avatar_file_size`, `avatar_updated_at`, `created_at`,
`name`, `path`, `type`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-12-1
9 15:10:31', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-12-19 15:10:31')←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (141.0ms)←[0m  COMMIT
Redirected to http://192.168.0.187:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 858ms (ActiveRecord: 277.0ms)
```

The table is getting null values for image path and image names as seen in the above console output. I am not getting as to where my image is getting stored and how to get the path to the image location.

And this is my `upload` method that is getting called:-

```
def upload
  @photo = ImgUploader.new(:avatar => params[:media])

  if @photo.save
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end    
end
```

Comment: Should I use media_content_type, media_file_name, media_file_size instead of avatar_content_type, avatar_file_name, avatar_file_size to get the result?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my problem after changing the fields to media as mentioned in the comment.

Thanks. Case closed.